# PHP Strtotime additional functionality

Tags: php, strtotime

The following code returns the first saturday of next month and the first saturday of the month after. With the first saturday of next month the only issue is that it allows the user to select a day even if it is tomorrow.

Say just coming up is the 2nd of April which is a saturday. At the moment a customer can book this day. However If the first saturday of next month is less than 8 days again I want the first and of this month and next month to default one month along further.

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));?>

<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
// Use 691200 for eight days.
if ((strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+1 month')) - mktime()) < 691200) {
    // Go two months.
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+3 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));
} else {
    // Go one month.
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))));
}
```